# Include subdirectories to organise code in ESP-IDF for ESP32

Tags: c, esp32, esp-idf

I'm using ESP-IDF 4.3.2 to create an ESP32 project with the following command:

`idf.py create-project --path test test`

I then modify main/main.c to contain the following code:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include "freertos/FreeRTOS.h"
#include "freertos/task.h"

void app_main(void)
{
    int i = 0;
    while (1) {
        printf("[%d] Hello world!\n", i);
        i++;
        vTaskDelay(5000 / portTICK_PERIOD_MS);
    }
}
```

This compiles and runs just fine, but if I try to create a subdirectory of main to organise my code I seem to hit an error.
I'll add `dosomething/printsomething.h` and `dosomething/printsomething.c` with the following contents:

`dosomething/printsomething.h`:

```
void printsomething(void);
```

`dosomething/printsomething.c`:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

void printsomething(void)
{
    printf("something\n");
}
```

I then modify `main.c` as follows:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include "freertos/FreeRTOS.h"
#include "freertos/task.h"

#include "dosomething/printsomething.h"

void app_main(void)
{
    int i = 0;
    while (1) {
        printf("[%d] Hello world!\n", i);
        printsomething();
        i++;
        vTaskDelay(5000 / portTICK_PERIOD_MS);
    }
}
```

The code fails to build and I see an "undefined reference to `printsomething'" error.

```
/home/builduser/.espressif/tools/xtensa-esp32-elf/esp-2021r2-8.4.0/xtensa-esp32-elf/bin/../lib/gcc/xtensa-esp32-elf/8.4.0/../../../../xtensa-esp32-elf/bin/ld: esp-idf/main/libmain.a(test.c.obj):(.literal.app_main+0x4): undefined reference to `printsomething'
/home/builduser/.espressif/tools/xtensa-esp32-elf/esp-2021r2-8.4.0/xtensa-esp32-elf/bin/../lib/gcc/xtensa-esp32-elf/8.4.0/../../../../xtensa-esp32-elf/bin/ld: esp-idf/main/libmain.a(test.c.obj): in function `app_main':
/home/builduser/Documents/code/esp/esp/test/build/../main/test.c:11: undefined reference to `printsomething'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.
ninja failed with exit code 1
```

I can see that the `main\CMakeLists.txt` file contains the following:

```
idf_component_register(SRCS "test.c"
                    INCLUDE_DIRS ".")
```

But I can't find the right syntax for INCLUDE_DIRS which will allow me to specify the directories where the C and Header files are.

Comment: How `idf_component_register(SRCS "test.c"` is related to `myinclude/printsomething.c`? How can cmake know what you mean?

Comment: I see what you mean, I tried duplicating the idf_component_register line in main/ like `idf_component_register(SRCS "printsomething.c" INCLUDE_DIRS "dosomething")` but that doesn't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a default folder for this. Create a folder called `components` and place the `dosomething` folder inside it. The `components` folder should not be created inside `main`, but in the same directory as `main`. So you can use `#include "printsomething.h"` and everything will work. You don't need to modify your `CMakeLists.txt`, as `components` is a default directory. See more [here](https://docs.espressif.com/projects/esp-idf/en/latest/esp32/api-guides/build-system.html#example-project).

Comment: This is the recommended way to do it in IDF.

Answer (score 2):

Im not exactly familiar with `cmake` and `ESP-IDF`. I use `platformio` in `nvim` and `make`. But try create in root directory `CMakeLists.txt` contains:

```
PROJECT(test)

SET(DIRS dosomething main)
SUBDIRS(${DIRS})
INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES(${DIRS})
```

In `main` directory `CMakeLists.txt` contains:

```
ADD_EXECUTABLE(test main.c)
TARGET_LINK_EXECUTABLE(test something)
```

And in `dosomething` dir `CMakeLists.txt` contains:

```
ADD_LIBRARY(something printsomething.c)
```

---

EDIT:

I took a test with your code in ESP-IDF:
`main/CMakeLists.txt`:

```
idf_component_register(SRCS "main.c"                                                                                
                INCLUDE_DIRS ".")
```

`main/main.c`:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "freertos/FreeRTOS.h"
#include "freertos/task.h"

#include "../dosomething/printsomething.c"

void app_main(void)
{                                                                                                                   
  int i = 0;                                                                                                      
  while (1) {                                                                                                     
    printf("[%d] Hello world!\n", i);                                                                           
    printsomething();                                                                                           
    i++;                                                                                                        
    vTaskDelay(5000 / portTICK_PERIOD_MS);                                                                      
  }                                                                                                               
}
```

`dosomething/CMakelists.txt`:

```
idf_component_register(SRCS "printsomething.c"                                                                      
                INCLUDE_DIRS ".")
```

`idf.py build` passed without a problem.

---

EDIT II:
On https://docs.espressif.com/projects/esp-idf/en/latest/esp32/api-guides/build-system.html?highlight=cmakelists#file-globbing-incremental-builds showed better cleaner way:

`main/Cmakelists.txt`:

```
idf_component_register(INCLUDE_DIRS "."                                                                             
                SRC_DIRS "./" "../dosomething")
```

`main/main.c`:

```
#include <stdio.h>                                                                                                  
#include "freertos/FreeRTOS.h"                                                                                      
#include "freertos/task.h"                                                                                          
                                                                                                                
                                                                                                                
#include "../dosomething/printsomething.h"                                                                          
                                                                                                                
void app_main(void)                                                                                                 
{                                                                                                                   
    int i = 0;                                                                                                      
    while (1) {                                                                                                     
        printf("[%d] Hello world!\n", i);                                                                           
        printsomething();                                                                                           
        i++;                                                                                                        
        vTaskDelay(5000 / portTICK_PERIOD_MS);                                                                      
    }                                                                                                               
}
```

That is all.

Comment: I couldn't reproduce your success until I #included the .c file instead of the .h file, as you show in your example.  This seems really odd to me - can you explain further?

Comment: @MattB not to forget do first `idf.py reconfigure` `idf.py build`